# Yii 2 Upload and Save Image Files Locally and Image URL is Saved in DB

Tags: php, image, upload, yii2

I have followed different implementation of file/image upload in Yii 2. One of which is from Kartik's widgets, which is in here: http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput

In my **view**, *_form.php*:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
   <?php
      // A block file picker button with custom icon and label
      echo FileInput::widget([
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'image',
                    'options' => ['multiple' => true],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'showCaption' => false,
                        'showRemove' => false,
                        'showUpload' => false,
                        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
                        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                        'browseLabel' =>  'Upload Receipt'
                    ],
                    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*']
                ]);
   ?>
</div>
```

I only showed you a part of my view. That image upload block is accompanied with other fields like Customer Name, Date From and To, Product Name, etc and a Submit button.

I also have models and controllers generated already.

Part of my **controller** is this:

```
   public function actionCreate()
   {
      $model = new Invoice();
      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
         return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->inv_id]);
      } 
      else {
         return $this->render('create', [
             'model' => $model,
         ]);
      }
   }
```

I have not added anything yet in my actionCreate because I still don't have any idea. And in Kartik's file upload demo, there are no controllers involved or shown.

How do I save the URL/path of the image I chose to upload in my database, and save that image locally?

**Edit:**

Regarding @arogachev's answer, here's what my afterSave looks like in my model, but still the image path is not saved in my db:

```
    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        if(isset($this->image)){
            $this->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($this,'image');
        if(is_object($this->image)){
            $name = Yii::$app->basePath . 'C:\wamp3\www\basicaccounting\web\uploads';  //set directory path to save image
            $this->image->saveAs($name.$this->inv_id."_".$this->image);   
            $this->image = $this->inv_id."_".$this->image;    //appending id to image name            
        Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
                  ->update('invoice', ['image' => $this->image], 'inv_id = "'.$this->inv_id.'"')
                  ->execute(); //manually update image name to db
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you misunderstood my variable `$name`  its just a path to a folder where we store img. Edited my ans.. print the output of each variable and see where u did mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below aftersave in your model

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    if(isset($this->logo)){
        $this->logo=UploadedFile::getInstance($this,'logo');
    if(is_object($this->logo)){
        $path=Yii::$app->basePath . '/images/';  //set directory path to save image
        $this->logo->saveAs($path.$this->id."_".$this->logo);   //saving img in folder
        $this->logo = $this->id."_".$this->logo;    //appending id to image name            
    \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
              ->update('organization', ['logo' => $this->logo], 'id = "'.$this->id.'"')
              ->execute(); //manually update image name to db
        }
    }
}
```

replace the above logo with your own attribute. ie. image

Comment: hi. thanks for this but it's not working. I edited my question, I put the afterSave in my model.

Comment: Why do you want to save the full path of image to db? Saving image name is enough.. If you save full path it wud b an headache for you while uploading it to server.

Answer (score 0):

Try given below -

In your Controller

```
if($model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image'))
{
    if ($model->upload())
    {
    // file is uploaded successfully
    }
}
```

In your Model

```
public function upload()
{
    $path = \Yii::$app->params['basepath'];
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
    $image_path = BaseFileHelper::createDirectory($path,0777,true);
    }
    $this->image->saveAs($path . date('Y').'/'.date('m').'/'.date('d').'/'.$this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension);
    $this->image = date('Y').'/'.date('m').'/'.date('d').'/'.$this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension; // Assign image path to store in Database column (image).
    return true;
}
```

Your image will be save on server as "$path . date('Y').'/'.date('m').'/'.date('d').'/'.$this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension".
and in the database it will be save as "date('Y').'/'.date('m').'/'.date('d').'/'.$this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension".

Answer (score 0):

In form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'images[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
       'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*', 'multiple' => true],
       'pluginOptions' => [
           'previewFileType' => 'image',
           'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp','jpeg'],
           'showUpload' => true,

           'overwriteInitial' => true,

       ],
   ]);
?>
```

In Model

```
public $images;
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'price'], 'required'],
        [['price'], 'integer'],
        [['images'],'file', 'maxFiles' => 4],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
    ];
}
```

In Controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();
         if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->save();

                $file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'images');
                       foreach ($file as $file) {
                        $path =Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/uploads/'.$file->name;
                          $file->saveAs($path);

            }

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```